# android authentication login password

Tags: android, restful-authentication

restful service in android  authenticating and connecting it to the url
new to android

unable to get the output : username password and connecting to the url

```
package com.example.newrestapi;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    EditText password,userName;
    Button login;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        password=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        userName=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        login=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        //progess_msz.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        progressBar=(ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                String s1=userName.getText().toString();
                String s2=password.getText().toString();
                new ExecuteTask().execute(s1,s2);

            }
        });
    }

    class ExecuteTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
    {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            String res=PostData(params);

            return res;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //progess_msz.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, 50000).show();
        }

    }

    public String PostData(String[] values) {
        String s="";
        try
        {
            HttpClient httpClient=new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet=new HttpGet("http://myrul");

            HttpResponse httpResponse=  httpClient.execute(httpGet);

            HttpEntity httpEntity=httpResponse.getEntity();

            s= readResponse(httpResponse);

        }
        catch(Exception exception)  {}
        return s;
    }


        public String readResponse(HttpResponse res) {
            InputStream is=null;
            String return_text="";
            try {
                is=res.getEntity().getContent();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                String line="";
                StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
                while ((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
                {
                    sb.append(line);
                }

                return_text=sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
            return return_text;
        }
    }
```

login authentication using android restful services

Comment: Can u tell me are u getting any error? or its crashing.? what is happening?

Comment: log cat needed pls

Comment: Where are you passing the parameters for the post request in the do inBackground.